# find sharepoint 2010 user login status

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, login, information-management

i need to find all share point users login status.
basically i need to create the basic live web chat (like Facebook chat) program with integrate with SharePoint users.
so i need to display all SharePoint users login status and how many users in online.

how do i find all SharePoint users login status programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for this thing. Microsoft is offering server based solutions not related to sharepoint at all. Look for Microsoft Lync 2013

http://lync.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/unified-communications.aspx

If installed and configured the precense of the user will lit up next to the people information of documents or contact webparts. Not excactly what you asked for but a highly professional solution (with a lot of cost and extra licenses attached to it).

Nothingbutsharepoint has a great overview of possible solutions for SharePoint 2010:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Instant-Messaging-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

The most practical approch would be to integrate a third party solution. I did a little web search for you on bing.com:

- http://lightningtools.com/lightning-chat/
- http://sharepointchat.codeplex.com/
- http://www.bing.com/search?q=sharepoint+2010+chat+webpart+-chart&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=sharepoint+2010+chat+webpart+-chart&sc=7-35&sp=-1&sk=

If you are able to integrate some javascript it might be possible to use something like SignalR from Microsoft. Check out Scott Hanselmans blog post:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx